# Assert an object to be deep equal to another with number or null field

Tags: javascript, chai

I have this object,

```
obj1 = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: 3 // or null,
}
obj2 = {
a: 1,
b: 2,
c: null // or 3
}
```

How can I assert deep equal on these object?

```
expect(obj1).to.deep.eql(obj2);
```

I know above doesn't work the way I want.

I need a or condition here that takes care of `null` or either `number` part.

I could do something like below.

```
expect(obj1.c).to.be.within([3, null])
delete obj1.c
delete obj2.c
expect(obj1).to.deep.eql(obj2)
```

Comment: Those aren't valid objects. Are you saying that `c` can be either 3 _or_ null?

Comment: Yes, of course. I updated.

Comment: Why doesn't it work the way you want`?

Comment: Deep equal will fail if c is 3 in one and null in another, I want them to expect c to be null also.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [AND/OR logical operators](https://github.com/damian-szulc/chai-json-pattern/blob/master/API.md#andor-logical-operators) of [chai-json-pattern](https://github.com/damian-szulc/chai-json-pattern) plugin.

```js
const chai = require('chai');
const chaiJsonPattern = require('chai-json-pattern').default;
chai.use(chaiJsonPattern);

const { expect } = chai;

describe('69158740', () => {
  it('should pass', () => {
    const obj1 = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 };
    const obj2 = { a: 1, b: 2, c: null };
    expect(obj1).to.matchPattern(`{
      "a": 1,
      "b": 2,
      "c": null OR 3
    }`);
    expect(obj2).to.matchPattern(`{
      "a": 1,
      "b": 2,
      "c": null OR 3
    }`);
  });
});
```

package versions:

```json
"chai-json-pattern": "^1.1.0",
"chai": "^4.2.0"
```